# Case insensitive CQL-OpenLayers filter?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, postgresql, cql-filter

I have the following filter in OpenLayers 2.13

```
var filter_c = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE,
        property: 'p_name', 
        value: '%'+document.getElementById("nm").value+'%'
})
```

I also use GeoServer 2.1.3 and PostgreSQL 9.1 / PostGIS 2.0.

This filter is case sensitive and is applied to a vector layer. I can provide more code if you want.

I try to use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` but no luck. What am I missing? How can I make this filter case insensitive?

Here is the complete, original code

```
var filter_c = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE,
    property: 'p_name', 
    value: '%'+document.getElementById("nm").value+'%'
});

//pass the filter to the layer
var prot =  new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    url:  "/geoserver/wfs",
    featureType: "pins",
    featureNS: "http://www.mysite.gr",
    defaultFilter: filter_cl
});

var _CallBack = function(resp) {
    pins.addFeatures(resp.features)
    var cb = pins.features.length;
    if (cb == 0){alert("Nothing Found");}
};

var response = prot.read({callback: _CallBack});


//refresh to render POIs
pins.refresh({force:true});
```

The `pins` layer takes data from a table in postgreSQL/PostGIS. This table has `id, name, geometry, category, etc.`Names are in `UTF8` and are in Greek, such as `Ακρόπολη, Παρθενώνας`etc.

I simply set it like `pins = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("LayerTitle", {renderers: ["Canvas", "SVG", "VML"]})` and the I have the aforementioned code to search it

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using GeoServer, you can use `strToLowerCase()` function, while passing the search term in lower case as well.

The following code should work:

```
var filter_c = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE,
        property: 'strToLowerCase(p_name)', 
        value: '%'+String(document.getElementById("nm").value).toLowerCase()+'%'
})
```

Comment: I try your code. I dont get the message "Nothing Found", but the map zooms in a random place and I still see no features on the layer. Maybe I should provide more of my code?

Comment: That would be useful. What's the source of your vector layer?